# delphi - how to get the progress of socket.SendStream?

Tags: delphi

I use dephi7's client/server socket components to send a file with tfilestream from client to server.

I'am able to get the progress of file received at server side,
but at client side, how do i get the progress of the file sent ?

this is how I send the file:

```
  fstream:=tfilestream.Create(opendialog1.FileName,fmOpenRead);
  clientsocket1.Socket.SendStream(fstream);
```

Thanks and appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't look like `TClientSocket` provides any feedback of its progress. I see two alternatives:

1. Instead of `SendStream`, use `TStream.Read` and `TClientSocket.Socket.SendBuf` in a loop. Read a block of data from the stream and then send it. Repeat until you reach the end of the stream.
2. Write a `TStream` descendant class that wraps (or *decorates*) another stream. Its `Read`, `Write`, and `Seek` methods can simply forward to the wrapped stream, but you can also add some events to the wrapper so you can be notified each time the socket code reads a block of data out of the stream — the `SendStream` method essentially does the same thing that I described above in the first alternative.